# Procedimiento almacenado me arroja dos año 2019 y 2020 y el año 2019 es el correcto

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

```
Alter procedure spFiltrarporTrunkyDirection    
    @TRUNK NVARCHAR(16),
    @DIRECTION NVARCHAR(4),
    @CALL_TIMEINICIO DATETIME2(0),
    @CALL_TIMEFINAL DATETIME2(0)
    AS
    BEGIN
    SELECT 
    EXT, CALLER_PHONE,  
    datename(DAY,convert(date,CALL_TIME))+' '
      +datename(MONTH,convert(date,CALL_TIME))
      +' '+datename(YEAR,convert(date,CALL_TIME)) as Fecha_Llamada, 
    convert (time(0),(DURATION)) as DURACION 
    FROM 
    PBXDATA
    WHERE 
      TRUNK LIKE '%'+@TRUNK+'%' 
      OR DIRECTION LIKE '%'+@DIRECTION+'%' 
      AND CALL_TIME >= @CALL_TIMEINICIO 
      AND CALL_TIME <=@CALL_TIMEFINAL
    GROUP BY duration,CALLER_PHONE,CALL_TIME, EXT    
    END

    EXECUTE spFiltrarporTrunkyDirection 9009, 'INT', '09-10-2019','28-10-2019'
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! supongo que es sql server? y tu pregunta no deja en claro cual es el problema.. no tenemos forma de saber porque el 2020 no debe ir...

Comment: Como estan los datos en el campo call_time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que a tu WHERE le faltan unos parentesis, en especial si lo que buscas que TENGAN que estar en el rango de fechas sin importar las demas columnas

Aca te dejo un ejemplo

```
WHERE 
    (TRUNK LIKE '%'+@TRUNK+'%' OR DIRECTION LIKE '%'+@DIRECTION+'%') 
     AND 
     (CALL_TIME >= @CALL_TIMEINICIO AND CALL_TIME <=@CALL_TIMEFINAL)
```

Asi mismo veo que tienes un execute debajo que pasa los parametros en formato YYYY-MM-DD que es el formato por defecto de datetime2

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Has un PRINT de @CALL_TIMEINICIO y @CALL_TIMEFINAL para que veas como esta interpretando la fecha y si lo esta haciendode manera correcta.

Comment: En efecto, según [la documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#converting-date-and-time-data) los string literals que acepta datetime2 van como `YYYY-MM-DD`. Los ejemplos que hay convirtiendo un `date` incluso leen es `MM-DD-YY`...

Comment: Para aclarar, los paréntesis se necesitan porque primero se evalúan los `AND` y luego los `OR`. Esto se explica en [la documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/language-elements/operator-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).